# Openshift DIY cartridge : java.net.SocketException: Permission denied on Spring:boot project

Tags: sockets, deployment, spring-boot, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am trying to deploy following open source project on my openshift v2 web console: 
https://github.com/jivesoftware/jive-sdk-java-springboot

**.action_hook**  start file

```
#!/bin/bash
# The logic to start up your application should be put in this
# script. The application will work only if it binds to
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05"
export JRE_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/jre"
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.9"
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin


PATH=$M2:$PATH
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/jive-sdk-java-springboot-master
mvn spring-boot:run -s $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/settings.xml
```

Build failure message:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 01:27 min
remote: [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-23T12:32:56-04:00
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/314M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli)
 on project jive-sdk-java-springboot: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to st
art embedded Tomcat servlet container: Tomcat connector in failed state -> [Help 1]
```

Full details

```
 remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:45.371  INFO 455129 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTempl
ateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:50.548  INFO 455129 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registerin
g beans for JMX exposure on startup
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:54.348 ERROR 455129 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to
start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
remote:
remote: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.
32]
remote:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.
32.jar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.
0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.j
ar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.
0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.
0.32.jar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedC
onnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer
(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebAppl
icationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
a:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicatio
nContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.REL
EASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [sprin
g-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE
.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at com.jivesoftware.sdk.ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.main(ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.java:16) [classes/:
na]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boo
t-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
remote:
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:54.351 ERROR 455129 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to
start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
remote:
remote: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8
.0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8
.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedC
onnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer
(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebAppl
icationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
a:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicatio
nContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.REL
EASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [sprin
g-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE
.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at com.jivesoftware.sdk.ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.main(ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.java:16) [classes/:
na]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boo
t-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
remote: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.
jar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8
.0.32]
remote:         ... 19 common frames omitted
remote: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.
32]
remote:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.
32.jar:8.0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.
0.32]
remote:         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.
jar:8.0.32]
remote:         ... 20 common frames omitted
remote:
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:54.750  INFO 455129 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping s
ervice Tomcat
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:55.256 DEBUG 455129 --- [ost-startStop-2] .j.s.s.f.JiveSignedFetchValidationFilter : JiveSigned
FetchValidationFilter destroying...
remote: 2016-10-23 12:32:56.056 ERROR 455129 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Applicatio
n startup failed
remote:
remote: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat ser
vlet container
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer
(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebAppl
icationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
a:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicatio
nContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.REL
EASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [sprin
g-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE
.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEAS
E.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at com.jivesoftware.sdk.ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.main(ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.java:16) [classes/:
na]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boo
t-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
remote: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
remote:         ... 16 common frames omitted

remote: [WARNING]
remote: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
remote:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
remote:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
remote:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
remote: Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded
 Tomcat servlet container
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:165)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer
(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebAppl
icationContext.java:141)
remote:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
a:541)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicatio
nContext.java:118)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
remote:         at com.jivesoftware.sdk.ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.main(ExampleJiveAddOnApplication.java:16)
remote:         ... 6 more
remote: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
remote:         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedS
ervletContainer.java:159)
remote:         ... 16 more
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 01:27 min
remote: [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-23T12:32:56-04:00
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/314M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli)
 on project jive-sdk-java-springboot: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to st
art embedded Tomcat servlet container: Tomcat connector in failed state -> [Help 1]
remote: [ERROR]
remote: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote: [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote: [ERROR]
remote: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have tried various things but I am not able to understand where is the problem?

From error message it looks like openshift is not allowing the application to run on port 8080. But as per this link (https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html)it should be port 8080.

I am not sure where the problem is ! Please help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with port 5701. I modified the manifest.yml to include this port, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: I figured out my issue. Which cartridge are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}
server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}
```

to application.properties or applicatons.yml file

(y)